# Save a mysql query to a string in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string, pdo

I am trying to execute in PHP a sql query and save it to a single string. The SELECT query will output a single cell of the table and I need it as a string.

```
$pdo1 = new PDO('mysql:host=dbIP;dbname=dbname', 'dbuser', 'pw');


$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT username FROM wcfusers WHERE email='$email");
```

I found some other methodes but they dont use the PDO. I would apreciate any kind of help. I hope someone can help me with my small problem.

Comment: See "fetch data using prepared statements" in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: That's not how you use a prepared statement.

Comment: @chris85 well, yes and no. `prepare/execute` even without a `?` or named placeholder is still valid. I think they're just wanting to know how to print the (successful) results.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @Fred-ii- well yea, I guess I should have said that's not how you **should** use prepared statements.

Comment: @chris85 you've a point there ;-)

Comment: This question looks like either a runaway or the question wasn't solved.

Answer (score 1):

Best place to go is always the PHP manual.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

See example 3: "Fetching data using prepared statements" which has

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM REGISTRY where name = ?");
if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET['name']))) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        print_r($row);
    }
}
?>
```

Note that this example also tells you how to safely pass in parameters (in your case, the email)